# gio: file:///tmp/....pdf: No application is registered as handling this file

Tags: python-3.x, fedora, gio

I have this code Python3.7 on Fedora 30 :

```
try :
    subprocess.call(["gio", "open", path_to_pdf])
```

On others linux systems, including Fedora 29, the standalone application generated with Pyinstaller runs fine.

But when I run this generated code on Fedora 30, I'm facing this error :

```
    gio: file:///tmp/tmpxxxxx.pdf: No application is registered as handling this file
```

Note :
I encountered some problem under Ubuntu/Mint/Debian, but could resolve it (acting on the system Linux) with that command :

```
    aa-complain /usr/bin/evince
```

Is this the same kind of blocking on Fedora 30 ?

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :

This issue came from some kind of incompatibility between Matplotlib 3.0.1, and Pyinstaller 3.4.
Upgrading to Matplotlib 3.0.3 solved the problem...